# installing PHP for IIS8 on a windows server 2012 machine?

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2012

We are running a web server IIS8 on a windows server 2012 machine. I need to install PHP on it.

I found a nice tutorial here: http://www.nutstech.info/2012/09/windows-server-2012-server-core-setup.html

But, I am hesitant to follow it, and would like to know whether anyone has had experience installing PHP for IIS8 on a win server 2012 machine and whether there is an easy way of doing this?

Please note that I will be using php scripts to run stored procedures on a sql server 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the TechNet article instead, or perhaps a blend of both. I see some warnings on the TechNet side about installing the non-thread version due to incompatibilities with PHP 5.4.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994578.aspx

Microsoft says the best way is to use their Web Installer from IIS.

Comment: thank you! it wasnt clear to me that the web installer installs php?

Comment: any ideas how i can install the cgi module?

Comment: Ignore step #4. http://wiki.webspellchecker.net/doku.php?id=installationandconfiguration:licensed:win2012#install_cgi_for_iis_server :)

Comment: Are you talking about the Windows CGI feature? or CGI module of PHP? According to that TechNet article, the Web PI install it (CGI) when it installs PHP.